# Mongodb Aggregation Framework Output Collection Indexes

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm building an API with a particular endpoint that returns various statistics for the entire database.

For this, I have an aggregation pipeline that takes 1 second to complete.

Instead of running this aggregation for every request, I want to store the results in a collection **c** as the aggregated data changes rarely and is accessed frequently.

I will also define a few indexes on **c** as I need to return only documents that mactch some criteria passed to the endpoint.

When the source data is changed, I'd run the aggregation again and replace the contents of collection **c**.

In MongoDB 3.0, the docs about the **out** operator of the aggregation pipeline state that:

> The $out operation does not change any indexes that existed on the previous collection

**I'm confused, does this mean that MongoDB won't update the indexes on *c* when its contents are replaced?**

P.S.: I know that MapReduce might be an alternative; I tried that first, but I did not manage to get the results I wanted; my current approach works and given the approaching deadline I'd like to simply "cache" the aggregated data instead of reimplementing this from scratch.

**EDIT**

What I'm asking is if the indexes will reflect the new documents after the replacement of the collection or if they will be "stale".

Comment: I expect it means it will preserve the existing indexes. But you may want to run a little test.

Comment: I'd hope people to know this as it seems quite a natural conern to have, but I agree with you that a little test is the ultimate proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index will be updated when you execute your Aggregate query.

- $out will create a collection when your aggregate query is successful
- Mongo will update your collection created by $out when you execute your aggregate again
- When the collection is updated, then the indexes associated with the collection is also updated

---

You can test this by following the below steps

- Create a smaller collection say 'books'

{ "_id" : 8751, "title" : "The Banquet", "author" : "Dante", "copies" : 2 }

- Have your aggregate with output collection - Step2

db.books.aggregate( [{ $group : { _id : "$author", books: { $push: "$title" } } },{ $out : "authors" }] )

- Create Index on books in the new collection authors

db.authors.createIndex({books:1})

- Query your author collection

db.authors.find({books:'The Banquet'}).explain()
and look for the winning plan
 - Add another record

db.books.insert({ "_id" : 7101, "title" : "Wings of Fire", "author" : "APJ Abdul Kalam", "copies" : 1 })

- Execute the aggregate query given on step2

Now do a find for the new book which we added

- db.authors.find({books:'Wings of Fire'}).explain()

### You can find that the Winning plan is having IXSCAN says that the index is used for this search and so the index is updated by Mongo for the new record.

MongoDB will preserve the existing indexes

Replace Existing Collection

If the collection specified by the $out operation already exists, then upon completion of the aggregation, the $out stage atomically replaces the existing collection with the new results collection. The $out operation does not change any indexes that existed on the previous collection. If the aggregation fails, the $out operation makes no changes to the pre-existing collection.

Reference:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I edited my question to better describe what I'm asking

Comment: Updated the answer as well :-)

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the fact that you also provided a quick example for people with similar questions to see for themeselves